# List of all Child B2BUnits

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

How to write a Flexible search Query to list all the Child B2BUnits of a Parent B2BUnit?

Ex: Parent B2BUnit: tc-0100
Child B2BUnit: tc-0101,tc-0102

If I search for Parent B2BUnit(tc-0100), I should get all the Child B2BUnits(tc-0101,tc-0102)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the children of the given b2bUnit(i.e **tc-0100**) with the following query:

```
select {pk} from {B2BUnit} where {pk} in ({{select {source} from {PrincipalGroupRelation} where {target}='$pkOfParentUnit$'}})
```

This flexible search query can be tried in hac after replacing **$pkOfParentUnit$** with the actual PK of the given unit tc-0100 (the PK can be seen in the "Administration" tab in backoffice)

Explanation:

The inner query :

```
({{select {source} from {PrincipalGroupRelation} where {target}='$pkOfParentUnit$'}})
```

fetches all the members of a group(and in our case all the members of the given B2B unit) including B2BCustomers that might be assigned to it.

The beginning of the query makes sure that only the B2BUnits are present in the result and not B2BCustomers or other objects that might be also members.